# PHP: turn list with repeating keys into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a key value list that looks like this:

```
running: "yes"
running_where: "to the store"
running_why: "because"
walking: "yes"
someotherkey: "some non related value"
walking_where: "over there"
walking_why: "mom told me to"
running: "yes"
running_where: "to the bank"
yetanotherkey: "yet another non related value"
running_why: "broke"
```

And so on. The groupings are in order (but there are sometimes other keys in the groupings that I want to ignore completely), and I would like to turn this into a usable array by grouping the associated items, which in the case above would give me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Group
        (
            [running] => yes
            [running_where] => to the store
            [running_why] => because
        )

    [1] => Group
        (
            [walking] => yes
            [walking_where] => over there
            [walking_why] => mom told me to
        )
    [2] => Group
        (
            [running] => yes
            [running_where] => to the bank
            [running_why] => broke
        )        
 )
```

What is the easiest way in PHP to accomplish this? I have looked at similar issues but haven't found one that applies yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code,

```
array_chunk($array, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't work in my case because there is extraneous info in and among the groupings, I will edit my question to make that more clear, sorry.